# automate bzr diff and bzr pull

Tags: version-control, automation, bazaar

To automate bazaar version control system with any changes in version control system (server) branch it will automate pull to locale node
to get the difference between branch created on version control system (server) and local node by

```
bzr diff
```

and then to pull code by using

```
bzr pull
```

but this make **every day job** to start **how to automate this**

Comment: What is exactly your question here ? And what do you want to achieve ? A simple synchronization between two bzr repositories ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your operating system's mechanism to schedule tasks. 
In Ubuntu/Linux you can add a crontab script.

Comment: But if the difference between server and local node then n then only pull will be done other wise there  is no need to pull so how we can figure out there is difference or not in cornjob

Comment: It is the same amount of effort to do a diff or a pull to determine the differences. So if you pull and there is no changes then it will just say there is nothing to pull. If you have local changes it will refuse to pull, but you can specify pull --overwrite if you want the remote version to replace your local version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use Bazaar in a centralized style. In Bazaar you can "bind" to a remote branch, which means that your commits in your local branch will be applied in the remote branch too.

```
bzr bind URL
```

... where URL is the branch you `bzr branch` or `bzr pull` from.

This way you can skip the everyday `bzr push`.

If you use the remote repository from multiple computers, you will still need to update the local branches before you start any work. (Well, you don't really "have" to, but if you prefer a simple workflow with no unintended diverged branches then you want to do this.) You can update bound branches with `bzr up` or `bzr pull`.